# All 8 processors at 100 %, very slow Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: drivers, 22.04

My Ubuntu 22.04 has suddenly become very slow. Gnome system monitor shows that all my 8 processors are running at 95-100 % with no active applications beside system monitor.
My system is an old Intel I7 with a Radeon R9 290/390 graphics card.

top gives me:

```
    [`PID ANVÄNDAR PR NI VIRT RES DELT S %CPU %MIN TID+ KOMMANDO
161426 root -51 0 0 0 0 S 50,2 0,0 88:49.15 kidle_i+
161427 root -51 0 0 0 0 S 50,2 0,0 88:47.38 kidle_i+
161430 root -51 0 0 0 0 S 50,2 0,0 88:50.43 kidle_i+
161431 root -51 0 0 0 0 S 50,2 0,0 88:49.29 kidle_i+
161433 root -51 0 0 0 0 S 50,2 0,0 88:50.61 kidle_i+
161428 root -51 0 0 0 0 S 49,8 0,0 88:48.78 kidle_i+
161429 root -51 0 0 0 0 S 49,8 0,0 88:46.63 kidle_i+
161432 root -51 0 0 0 0 S 49,8 0,0 88:49.63 kidle_i+
3250 he 20 0 505200 503320 1000 S 6,5 3,1 24:05.73 dbupdate
965435 he 20 0 430960 429112 1032 S 6,5 2,6 14:18.88 dbupdate
359123 he 20 0 457328 455480 1032 S 6,2 2,8 18:18.39 dbupdate
1364862 he 20 0 420464 418612 1032 S 6,2 2,6 11:31.47 dbupdate
1565188 he 20 0 417392 415548 1032 R 6,2 2,6 9:55.94 dbupdate
2738128 he 20 0 400752 398900 1032 S 6,2 2,5 3:42.22 dbupdate
1761549 he 20 0 414064 412216 1032 S 5,9 2,5 8:41.19 dbupdate
2159847 he 20 0 407152 405300 1032 S 5,9 2,5 6:38.14 dbupdate
3698445 he 20 0 390512 388660 1032 R 5,9 2,4 0:08.31 dbupdate
`]
```

What can be wrong?
H
PS posted this on Ubuntu forums but there seems to be hardly any activity

Comment: Run the command `htop` and find out the programs with highest CPU usage. Alternatively, use the GUI tool System Monitor

Comment: Your system appears to be throttling, based on the kidle_inject (I assume, the text seems to be truncated) times. I suggest using turbostat (linux tools common package, I think) and monitor things (such as processor temperature) with this command `sudo turbostat --Summary --show Busy%,Bzy_MHz,IRQ,PkgWatt,PkgTmp,RAMWatt,GFXWatt,CorWatt --interval 10` The big spew of stuff when tubostat starts up should reveal if there is and/or has been a thermal event.

Comment: Thanks. I think it was a hardware problem, taking off and putting back the lid did the trick and the machine seems healthy. If the problem returns I will vacuum the dusty interior. I had no success installing turbostat.